# how to find all the minted NFT on my Solana marketplace

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex

imagine I'm going to create a marketplace on Solana, every user can create and mint NFT using their own wallet, for minting, I'm using Metaplex js library, I need a way to get all of minted NFT data from on chain and store data in my own database, because every user mints NFT with their own wallet and I don't know how should I find all minted NFT in my marketplace, what is the best approach to implement it, should I add some data to NFTs to be able detect them or is there any other way to do this? what do other marketplaces do to handle this part?

I checked Metaplex document and seems we have some functions to load nft data using owner or creator
https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js#findallbyowner

but I can't use it because every users mint NFT using their own wallet.